# Why is Thread.Sleep is not precise for long durations?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a service written in C#. Service is active around the clock but one thread sleeps via Thread.Sleep till a predetermined time - typically 9PM - 11pm - to perform some housekeeping tasks. First time service starts, it calculates time span in mseconds till the housekeeping time and calls Thread.Sleep using that time span. Next time the thread simply calls Thread.Sleep(24*60*60*1000) to sleep 24 hours.

It works just  fine except a **single installation** when Sleep wakes few minutes earlier - 5-8 minutes earlier according to the trace log. Over several weeks, housekeeping time shifts few hours. I can expect that the housekeeping time can shift forward - not backwards. Wondering if anyone can have an explanation.  I must admit that I am not looking for a different solution to fix the problem - just trying to explain the behavior.

Comment: Is the system clock itself drifting on that machine?

Comment: Don't use sleep.

Comment: Maybe the system clock is getting reset somewhere? For debugging, you could have another thread that prints a log line every 10 minutes

Comment: Have you tried to use "Scheduled Tasks"? You may also want to give this a try http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: Quartz.NET is the Hero in these cases

Comment: I just want to stress that there are many better solutions to execute a code at given time . The question I have in this post is it possible that Sleep() will drift several minutes in 24 hours timespan? REmember it happens only on one installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thread.Sleep is not designed for long accurate sleeps like you are doing. You should be using somthing like [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). You can give it a first run time of midnight, and have it go off every 24 hours. the `Timer(TimerCallback, Object, TimeSpan, TimeSpan)` constructor is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Is accuracy of Sleep defined somewhere? What concerns me is that this substantial drift occurs only on one server. Hundreds servers are just fine. I am afraid that something happens on that machine that may affect other solutions. But what?

Answer (score 4):

Sleep doesn't use wall clock for time calculations.  It uses regular interrupt intervals which come approximately every 10ms (adjustable and OS version dependent) for this.  The time source which is used for these interrupts is a cheap quartz which was historically was used for some other functions, so its frequency is both not exactly 1/10ms and fluctuates from one machine to another.

The correct approach to solving your problem would be sleeping for much shorter periods of time and checking if the time has come to wake up for real.

Also, here's hoping that when you say you're using Sleep(), in fact you're waiting for an event with a timeout.

Comment: I would say the "correct approach" is to use a Timer, but that may just be me ;-) +1 otherwise.

Comment: @pst: thanks :)  Timer is correct, but it's only available on .NET.  The approach above is portable and would work on any platform.  Actually, I won't be surprised to learn that this is how the Timer is implemented too (I don't know for sure)